# Install Lyx in OpenSuse - libboost_regex problem

Tags: opensuse, latex, boost

I am trying to install lyx in opensuse with

```
   sudo zypper in lyx
```

However, I get the following error

```
Problem: nothing provides libboost_regex.so.1.53.0()(64bit) needed by lyx-2.1.3-109.1.x86_64
 Solution 1: do not install lyx-2.1.3-109.1.x86_64
 Solution 2: break lyx-2.1.3-109.1.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies
```

Now, I have 1.54 installed and I have downloaded 1.53 and installed it, and also added this older one to the path to try and find it, however the same error message shows up

Comment: Don't mix source packages and binary ones. You're going to get in trouble. Also, did you do an `ldconfig` after installing?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm....let's take a look:

```
zypper info libboost_regex1_53_0
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...


Information for package libboost_regex1_53_0:
---------------------------------------------
Repository: openSUSE-13.1-Oss
Name: libboost_regex1_53_0
Version: 1.53.0-4.1.2
Arch: x86_64
Vendor: openSUSE
Installed: Yes
Status: up-to-date
Installed Size: 1.0 MiB
Summary: The Boost::Regex runtime library
Description: 
This package contains the Boost::Regex runtime library.
```

Well...`libboost_regex` is in the Oss repo; and so is `lyx`.

Try installing is that way: `zypper in libboost_regex1_53_0`

If that doesn't work then:

`zypper in http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/13.1/repo/oss/suse/x86_64/libboost_regex1_53_0-1.53.0-4.1.2.x86_64.rpm`

This is all assuming that you are using OpenSuSE 13.1 if you have a different version. Then let me know.